# Getting ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly using Sklearn Pipeline, ColumnTransformer

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I'm working on a project involving Twitter data. I'm trying to run CountVectorizer on several text columns, and OHE on other categorical columns.

I keep getting the '*all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly*' error when trying to fit my pipeline and/or grid search after creating my column transformers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sktime
import nltk
from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from category_encoders import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


X = data[['geo_enabled','post_day_of_week', 'is_retweet', 'is_quote_tweet', 'tweet_text_no_mentions_urls', 'hashtags', 'user_mentions', 'tweet_source']]

y = data['category']

#stemming Arabic text
def stem_words(text):
    st = ISRIStemmer()
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    new_words = [st.pre32(word) for word in words]
    new_words2 = [st.suf32(word) for word in new_words]
    return [st.norm(word,num=3) for word in new_words2]

#text cols for nlp processing
nlp_features = ['tweet_text_no_mentions_urls','hashtags', 'user_mentions']
#categorical columns for OHE
cat_features = ['geo_enabled','post_day_of_week','is_retweet', 'is_quote_tweet','tweet_source']

#transformers
nlp_transformer = CountVectorizer()
cat_transformer = OneHotEncoder()

#Column Transformer preprocessor
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ('nlp', nlp_transformer,nlp_features),
    ('cat', cat_transformer, cat_features)
])

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', MultinomialNB())])

params = {
    'preprocessor__nlp__analyzer': ['word', stem_words],
    'preprocessor__nlp__stop_words': [None, 'arabic'],
    'preprocessor__cat__use_cat_names': [True],
    'preprocessor__cat__handle_unknown': ['ignore']
}

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,stratify=y, random_state=123)

gs = GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=params,n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Heres the full traceback of the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-316-84bf55be5253> in <module>
----> 1 gs.fit(X_train,y_train)

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    878             refit_start_time = time.time()
    879             if y is not None:
--> 880                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    881             else:
    882                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    339         """
    340         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 341         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    342         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    343                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    301                 cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    302             # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 303             X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    304                 cloned_transformer, X, y, None,
    305                 message_clsname='Pipeline',

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 352         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    752     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    753         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 754             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    755         else:
    756             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    528         self._validate_output(Xs)
    529 
--> 530         return self._hstack(list(Xs))
    531 
    532     def transform(self, X):

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _hstack(self, Xs)
    600         else:
    601             Xs = [f.toarray() if sparse.issparse(f) else f for f in Xs]
--> 602             return np.hstack(Xs)
    603 
    604     def _sk_visual_block_(self):

<__array_function__ internals> in hstack(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\time\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    344         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    345     else:
--> 346         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
    347 
    348 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 55439
```